# dllwrap could not work with <iostream>?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, mingw

dllwrap is the tool of the GNU GCC in mingw .It be used to build .dll file like gcc or g++.but I found it did not work well with  like below:

hello3.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
extern "C"   void MyDllSay( void )
   {
   }
```

hello3.def

```
LIBRARY hello3.dll
EXPORTS 
MyDllSay               @1 
hello = MyDllSay     @2
```

the compiler code is

> g++.exe -c -O3 hello3.cpp
>
> dllwrap.exe -o hello3.dll hello3.o --def hello3.def  --output-lib
>   libhello3.a

the error report is

> hello3.o:hello3.cpp:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to
>   `std::ios_base::Init::~I nit()'
>   hello3.o:hello3.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc): undefined reference to`
>   std::ios_base:: Init::Init()' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

if I set the hello3.cpp like this

```
//#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
extern "C"   void MyDllSay( void )
   {

   }
```

or like this

```
//#include<iostream>
extern "C"   void MyDllSay( void )
   {

   }
```

everything is fine.
How to make dllwrap work with iostream?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help !

Comment: What's wrong with using `g++ -shared`?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the a option in dllwrap .It worked well,I will check it further .
but i can't find the explaintion in [dllwrap old wiki](http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/dllwrap)

the option is

> -lstdc++
>   the new compiler is 
>   dllwrap.exe -o hello3.dll hello3.o --def hello3.def  --output-lib
>   libhello3.a -lstdc++